# What is the point of the [category] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I discovered the [category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category) tag earlier today, which seems to have no well-defined purpose. It has roughly 2,000 questions and seems to be highly ambiguous in usage. The tag wiki is not very helpful.

> A category is a grouping of information or data, which can be used for grouping, sorting, indexing, and searching.

Roughly 800 of these are also tagged [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and seem to refer to the specific notion of a category in Wordpress. Among the other questions tagged [category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category), some seem to be referring to the mathematical concept of a category (a la category theory), some are referring to categories on Wikipedia, some seem to be referring to categorical variables in R, and some simply use the tag to indicate that they have a collection of things.

This tag is clearly being used for different things, and aside from the Wordpress questions, its usage seems to be all over the map. Should we split this into multiple tags and then get rid of the ambiguous [category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category)? Or should we decide on some correct definition for [category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category) and start removing the tag from non-conforming questions? Or perhaps we should simply nuke it from orbit and move on.

Comment: I would propose another path: burn it with fire. I don't see any use in a [tag:category] tag.

Comment: It is a pretty typical contextual tag.  [wordpress] is top, also [php] and [magento].  They do match concepts in those programming, erm, categories.  Quite harmless, very far removed from what you do every day.  It is a big world out there, immigrants are welcome at SO.

Comment: This tag should get added to the burninated [category].

Comment: I [category]cally agree.

Comment: This is a bad [category].

Comment: I quickly went through all the questions that contained `[category]` in combination with `[category-theory]`, `[functional-programming]`, `[haskell]`, `[scala]`, `[coq]`, `[agda]`, `[idris]`, in all those cases it was sufficient to retag it as `[category-theory]`. In my personal opinion, it's not needed for questions about category theory. I cannot say anything about `[wordpress]` and `[excel]` and all the other stuff.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Wordpress is a perpetal dumpster fire since it exists mainly for plugin dev (on topic) not administration (off-topic) that's better off on [Wordpress.SE](//wordpress.stackexchange.com) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51078262))

Comment: @Machavity Is there some reason you didn't vote to close that example?

Comment: @HansPassant What benefit do "contextual tags" (which have been explicitly rejected by site policy for literally years) have over just including the word itself in the title or in your search?

Comment: @jpmc26 I think I was out of CVs at the time (been doing a lot in [ibm]). I've added one

Comment: Let me be [category]-ic here. This tag needs to dissapear.

Comment: Shouldn't [tag:bucket] be a new-speak synonym?

Answer (score 11):

Collecting the thoughts expressed in comments, which all seem to have significant support:

- [category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category) should be burninated because it is fundamentally useless due to being vague and applied to a myriad of topics.
- Questions also tagged with one of [category-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category-theory), [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming), [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell), [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala), [coq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coq), [agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agda), [idris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idris) can be retagged to [category-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category-theory).
- Many of the [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) questions are off-topic.
- We still like puns in our burnination process.

Comment: "We still like puns in our burnination process." I thought it was a requirement.